# Why do I need to allow Dropbox to integrate with Twitter if all it’s asking me to do is follow?

Tags: twitter, dropbox, twitter-integration

On [this Dropbox web page](https://www.dropbox.com/getspace), it says that I can get some free Dropbox space if I follow Dropbox on Twitter. (Notice this is a separate item from **Connect your Twitter Account** which is listed above that.)

[image]

When I click on the link that says “Follow Dropbox on Twitter,” it asks me to authorize a whole bunch of Twitter integration (much more than just following). See image:

[image]

Is there any way to get this free bonus without all of this full integration with Twitter? I did start to follow Twitter on my account but obviously there is nothing that tells Dropbox that this is my Dropbox account.

Comment: Couldn't you just Authorize the App, then turn around in Twitter and remove the app from the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropbox has Twitter integration, not just for promotional purposes (which is definitely one  of the reasons).

If you link your Twitter account with Dropbox, you will be able to share files on Twitter (through the Dropbox website) and hence the "Post Tweets for you" & "See who you follow" privileges are required by Dropbox.

I'm not sure of why it would require to read your Twitter timeline and/or update your profile, but I guess it comes as a standard package of privileges from Twitter.

Also, as pointed out in a comment on the above answer, you can always unlink your Twitter account after you get the free space.

Answer (score 2):

It's purely promotional. Once connected you can tweet your referral link to your Twitter followers and by promoting the service, Dropbox is giving you a reward.

[Source](http://lifehacker.com/5796318/the-cheapskates-guide-to-getting-free-dropbox-space) and [source](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1930467).

Image source:

[image]

Comment: I did it, got the credit, and then removed the authorization and the tweet.

Answer (score 0):

The title of this question and the body ask two different questions, but I will answer both:

**"Why do I need to allow Dropbox to integrate with Twitter if all it’s asking me to do is follow?"**

You answered this question yourself:

> I did start to follow Twitter on my account but obviously there is nothing that tells Dropbox that this is my Dropbox account.

Dropbox needs a way to formally associate your Dropbox account with your Twitter account. Otherwise, it can't give you credit.

**"Is there any way to get this free bonus without all of this full integration with Twitter?"**

Unfortunately, no, there is not. The work around (until such a time as Dropbox disables it) is what you wrote that you did in another comment: Integrate, follow @Dropbox, and de-integrate.